Troubleshooting Aorus 15 BSF randomly freezes with Crucial RAM
I've noticed annoying behavior in my Aorus 15 BSF laptop once I upgraded RAM.
This is Windows 11 laptop with i7-13700H, 4070 GPU and out of the box with 2 8GB DDR5-4800 memory sticks from Samsung (M425R1GB4BBO). Which I have updated it to 2 32 GB DDR5-4800 memory sticks from Crucial (CT2K32G48C40S5).
Everything is working most of the time. But every now and then whole system just freezes. No BSOD, no error, nothing. Just complete freeze of system and only forced shutdown by long pressing power button helps. I noticed that this is only happening with Crucial RAM. I have tried doing some investigation but no luck so far.
I checked Windows Memory Diagnostic, Memtest86+ (both steps as recommended by official suport page https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-memory/diagnosing-memory-problems). I also tried some additional stress-testing software called RAM Test (https://www.karhusoftware.com/ramtest/#introduction) but no luck. No issue is ever reported.
What's more - the crush can happen completely randomly. I can be doing heavy computational tasks and can run smoothly, while can freeze while browsing some basic webpages. Or the opposite can happen as well. Also, there can be months or days between freezes.
All of the system components to the best of my knowledge are updated to latest one.
Honestly, the most annoying thing is that I don't know what might be causing this. And without that I am not sure if for example getting new set of same RAM sticks would resolve the issue or not.
Does anyone have any suggestion how better I can troubleshoot this issue?

Did you remove the new RAM and try it? That seems to me to be the pretty clear most likely culprit. If you haven't done that yet, do it. Put the old RAM back in if it was removed, or if you've discarded it already, get different RAM and install it, and see if the issue reoccurs.

Yes, I did try that. At some point freezes started to annoy me to much and I replaced RAM back to original ones. No more issues.
So what you are suggesting is that it can indeed be new RAM, despite not reporting any issues in testing? That has been my best guess so far, but I was expecting to see something else as well to confirm issue with RAM.

Tests can't show everything. You've already solved your own problem: It's the RAM. I too feel the need to get confirmation from elsewhere, but the evidence you've already collected is the best evidence you can get, so trust it.

OP notes they had removed the new RAM and returned to the old RAM and the symptoms went away. This information was not included originally, but it confirms the problem is the RAM.
The solution is to replace new RAM.

It may be that the new RAM is a red herring.
I am unsure if your device falls into this category, but there is a problem with 13th and 14th gen intel CPUs: without a specific BIOS update to help mitigate it, they will progressively degrade.
I forget the specifics but normal operation damages the CPU and will progress to unusable state without the mitigation. Look into BIOS updates for your laptop and decide if you might need/want to RMA the device (or CPU) if the manufacturer's BIOS did not have this mitigation at the time of purchase.
See, for example ( https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2024/08/fix-for-intel-cpu-crashes-causes-minor-situational-slowdowns-requires-bios-update/ )
